# Bootstrap Nav not showing active tab's content

Tags: nav, bootstrap-4

I am using below bootstrap nav in my new website.
https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_pills_dynamic&stacked=h

When i am changing active tab( tab1 to tab2), it's still showing earlier active tab's contents.
Is there any way to resolve the issue.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Have you included all of the Bootstrap assets? You might be missing `bootstrap.min.js` and/or `jquery`.

Are there any errors in your JS console?

Make sure you have all of these CDNs linked (or that you've downloaded these files locally and linked them in your HTML):

```js
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-A7FZj7v+d/sdmMqp/nOQwliLvUsJfDHW+k9Omg/a/EheAdgtzNs3hpfag6Ed950n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js" integrity="sha384-DztdAPBWPRXSA/3eYEEUWrWCy7G5KFbe8fFjk5JAIxUYHKkDx6Qin1DkWx51bBrb" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vBWWzlZJ8ea9aCX4pEW3rVHjgjt7zpkNpZk+02D9phzyeVkE+jo0ieGizqPLForn" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

[Bootstrap 4 Docs](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/)

Comment: Please go through this link

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_pills_dynamic&stacked=h

Comment: after changing active tab, still its showing earlier active tab's contents

Comment: The tabbing works on the link. If you copy and paste all that code (especially the `link` and `script` tags in the `head`), you will see it function for you locally. The [link](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_pills_dynamic&stacked=h) you sent is using Bootstrap 3, but you tagged your question as Bootstrap 4. Which version of Bootstrap are you using?

Comment: am using bootstrap 3 only, please check the link i sent you,

Comment: Earlier my active tab was 'Home' with content :'HOME
Lorem ipsum dolor sit ame'. After Changing active tab to 'menu1, still its showing earlier home tab's contents instead of menu1 tab's contents